# EnableViewState Question in nested user controls - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page with (EnableViewState = "true") that has a parent control with (EnableViewState = "true"). The parent control loads a child control.

In the child control, I have a viewstate object that gets assigned to null on postbacks. The strange thing is if I set EnableViewState = "true" on the child control, then everything works fine.

My understanding was this directive is true by default. How does it matter whether I set this explicitly or not.

Comment: The EnableViewState property, when not set, is true by default with exception of LiteralControl and those loaded by CheckBoxList, Wizzard and some other controls. Which control loads which?

Answer (score 3):

If you use LoadControl() to load the controls, asp.net don't know how to restore those controls on postback.
If you however make sure all controls are loaded in Page_Init, then the view state will be loaded into the controls.

This [control](http://www.denisbauer.com/ASPNETControls/DynamicControlsPlaceholder.aspx) does some of these things for you

Answer (score 0):

Is ViewState turned off in the web.config?

Comment: No, its not turned off in web.config

Comment: Is that control dynamically added, with LoadControl method in codebehind?